# Commutative and associative exponentiation

Tags: abstract-algebra

As you know, exponentiation as a binary operation is neither commutative nor associative: $$a^b \neq b^a$$ in general and $$(a^b)^c \neq a^{(b^c)}$$But we can, with a little poking around, find a "commutative version" of exponentiation. Indeed, by defining $$a \wedge b = (a+b)^{ab+1}$$we see that we have generalised exponentiation to a commutative operation (we can write every exponentiation as a $\wedge$ and every $\wedge$ as an exponentiation, the neutral element of this new operation is $0$ and the inverse of $a$ is $-a$). My question is then: is it possible to determine such a procedure to give exponentiation associativity? And if so, is it possible to do so while preserving commutativity, and why not even distributivity with respect to multiplication? If it is impossible, what are the reasons?

Comment: It's not clear to me what "generalized exponentiation" means here. You've given the summary "we can write every exponentiation as as $\wedge$ and every $\wedge$ as an exponentiation," but this is pretty vague: to express $a\wedge b$ in terms of exponentiation we need to use additional operations (namely addition, multiplication, and a constant for $1$), and in the other direction I don't actually see a way to express $a^b$ in terms of $a\wedge b$ in any nice way.

Comment: Not in a "nice way" that's true, but this is not necessary

Comment: Actually I don't immediately see *any* way to do it. What method do you have in mind?

Comment: Well you can solve the equation $a \wedge b = c^d$, in other words : $$\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2-4d+4}}{2} \wedge \frac{c+\sqrt{c^2-4d+4}}{2} = c^d$$is an example of solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $a\land b:=a^{\ln b}$. Then

$$a\land (b\land c)=a\land b^{\ln c}=a^{\ln(b^{\ln c})}=a^{\ln b \ln c}=\left(a^{\ln b}\right)^{\ln c}=a^{\ln b}\land c=(a\land b)\land c,$$

so we have associativity. We have commutativity as well:

$$a\land b = a^{\ln b}=e^{\ln(a^{\ln b})}=e^{\ln a \ln b}=e^{\ln (b^{\ln a})}=b^{\ln a}=b\land a.$$

For the identity element, we have $e$, and the inverse elements $a^{-1}=e^{1/\ln a}$.

Finally, distributivity over multiplication? Yes:

$$a\land (b\cdot c)=a^{\ln(b\cdot c)}=a^{\ln b+\ln c}=a^{\ln b}\cdot a^{\ln c}=(a\land b)\cdot(a\land c).$$